# Solve a recurrence that has two forms for $n$ even or odd

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, recurrence-relations, closed-form, recursion

I am very new to recurrence, I became able to solve the most basic once.

But now I found one that has a different form, depending on n if it is even or odd:

the base case a(0) is 0.

for $n$ even: $a(n) = 2a(n-1) + 2^{n+1}$

for $n$ odd:  $a(n) = 2a(n-1) + 2^{n}$

I don't even know how to start, I was able to compute some values maybe I would see a pattern but I don't know how to go further.

Comment: Sorry I fixed it.  it was $a(n-1)$

Comment: There are lots of powers of $2$ involved here. You might try to spot the pattern of early terms in $b(n)=a(n)/2^n$ and rewrite the recurrences in terms of $b(n)$

Answer (score 2):

You can combine them into one recurrence for just the even terms.  For $n$ even we have $n-1$ is odd, so we can write
$$a(n)=2a(n-1)+2^{n+1}\\
a(n-1)=2a(n-2)+2^{n-1}\\
a(n)=4a(n-2)+3\cdot 2^{n}$$
Solve this recurrence to get the even terms, then apply the odd recurrence to the formula to get the odd terms.  If it makes it easier for you, you can define $m=\frac n2$ and write the recurrence in terms of $m$ to get the term on the right to be the $(m-1)^{st}$ term.

Comment: Can I get another hint

Comment: Can you solve this recurrence?  I eliminated the problem you identified, that the recurrence changed between even and odd terms.

Comment: I don't know how to deal with a powers inside the recurrence.
We usually deal with geometric or arithmetic series.

Comment: Henry's suggestion is a good one.  Define (for even $n$) $b(n)=a(n)2^{-n}$.  Rewrite the recurrence in terms of $b$.  That gets rid of the powers of $2$.

Comment: I ll try that thanks